# What could be the best practice to handle two dependent polymer js component communication

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have two polymer js component which are dependent on each other for functionality.

```
<polymer-component1 for='anotherCompo'> </polymer-component1>
<polymer-component2 id='anotherCompo'> </polymer-component2>
```

I want to be assured that both component are fully ready to communicate with each other. 
What mechanism should work here ?
event dispatcher and listen it in another component or any other. please suggest.

Comment: What exactly send from one component to other. Data? or you want to fire ones functions from other. Please try to explain the details about functionality you want to do.

Comment: You could dispatch a "ready" event from the parent element and listen to it in the children. I think both children should be fully initialized when the parent's ready/attached callback gets called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing changes to data between Polymer elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689969/sharing-changes-to-data-between-polymer-elements)